# Deleting a NIC using wmic

Tags: windows, cmd, wmi, virtualbox, wmic

I am trying to remove a lot of Virtualbox NICs that were created with docker toolbox using the command line (clicking them one for one is too much work and I will probably need to do this more in the future). So far I have the following command:

```
wmic nic where Description="VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" delete /INTERACTIVE
```

Interactive is there so I can double check. However when it tries to delete the first adapter I get the following error:

```
ERROR: 
Description = Provider is not capable of the attempted operation
```

I am executing this command as administrator.

How can I delete these (virtual host only) NIC's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to remove all Virtualbox adapters, using the following command:

```
devcon remove *VBox*
```

For this to work you need to download the DevCon utility. I got it for Windows 7 here: http://techlikes.com/2010/09/25/devcon-problem-in-windows-7-solved.html#comment-196743312